# React Native run two different apps on two independent AVDs

Tags: react-native, android-virtual-device, metro-bundler

I'm trying to run two different RN apps and debug it independently. But have problems.
Two apps placed in different repos (folders).
I created two Android Virtual Devices via Android Studio (deviceIds: "andr1" and "andr2").

In terminal I run:
`emulator -port 9988 -avd andr1`
to start specific AVD for the first app on port 9988

When I have running AVD I run:
`react-native run-android --port=8081 --deviceId=emulator-9988`
to run app on AVD with deviceId "emulator-9988".
Logically seems that deviceId formed dynamically by port on which AVD is run

I think in a way that I have running AVD on port 9988 and Metro bundler on port 8081 and it should work. But this is how in looks after build process completed:

[How it looks after build - screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P816N.png)

New external termanal with Metro is running and first terminal build process is finished.
App is running but Metro not see changes and not update app.

Ok.. I run:
`emulator -port 9999 -avd andr2`
and
`react-native run-android --port=8082 --deviceId=emulator-9999`
for second app.

It works! For the first try in each AVD runs two independent apps. But they are not tracked by Metro bundler. If I want to update apps I need to run these two commands again:
`react-native run-android --port=8081 --deviceId=emulator-9988`
`react-native run-android --port=8082 --deviceId=emulator-9999`

The question is - how I can use Metro bundler to update apps changes in realtime?

I try many instructions from Medium and etc but nowhere not found any acceptable solution.

======

dependencies:
"react-native": "^0.71.6",
"react-native-gradle-plugin": "^0.71.19",

Answer (score 0):

Fixed!
The problem was in ports.

I run:

`adb -s emulator-9988 reverse tcp:9988 tcp:8081`

`adb -s emulator-9988 reverse tcp:9999 tcp:8082`

This way a linked every AVD from their tcp ports 9988 and 9999 to metro bundler ports 8081 and 8082

This way debug apps can communicate with metro.